# How to read a dicom file on matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dicom, medical

I have a dicom file of size 256*256*3. However, when I read this file using dicomread command in matlab the size of the dicom file is 256*256? How to fix this ?

```
`close all;
clear all;
clear all;
%here we are reading the image and adding noise into that image.
sigma = 25;% standard deviation
P ='C:\Users\kitty\Dropbox\denoise_ksvd\ADNI';
D=dir(fullfile(P,'*.dcm'));
C=cell(size(D));
for k=1:numel(D)
    C=dicomread(fullfile(P,D(k).name));
   IMin0(:,k)=C(:);
end `
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not a matlab expert. However, you are apparently trying to read a volume which constitutes from multiple single-frame images. To do this, the [Matlab documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomread.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop) says that you need to use [dicomreadVolume](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomreadvolume.html) to do so. `dicomreadVolume` accepts a directory as input, reads all files in the directory and builds a 4D volumetric dataset from it.

Again, I am not too familiar with matlab, but I think your code to read the files should read:

```
P ='C:\Users\kitty\Dropbox\denoise_ksvd\ADNI';
X=dicomreadVolume(P);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19080073)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: Thanks, edited the answer accordingly

Comment: A little bit more explanation would be much better. :)

Comment: @VividD: as far as I see it, this answer is really complete. The rest is in the question. The DICOM file is a volume (more than one slice in one file), so dicomreadvolume is the recommended approach to read the file. What are you missing?

Comment: I am not missing anything, I am trying to help you put together a nicer answer. For example, just imagine that the links from your answer are dead, and write the answer so that in can be "stand-alone". Even quoting the documentation would be much better. The problem is that in three years, it is likely that the links won't work.

Comment: @VividD: Yes, I got you that way. So thank you for your hints. However, I am not a matlab expert, I wanted to give the hint that dicomreadvolume should be preferred over dicomread. Anyway, thanks to your hint I edited the answer now so that it should be reproducible when the links go dead.

Comment: This is way better, thanks. Yuo surpassed my expectations.

Comment: I personally see nothing wrong with an answer that says this is the function you want now read the documentation.  The edits are fine and more informative.  The question was how do I read this?  Answer use this other function.